# How to Retrieve float from sqlite database to C# textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

My code is working properly except when I try to Retrieve float/reel number from database , it return only the integer part as the screenshots shows.
the value in the database is 145.55 but the textbox show 145 only.

*I tried with MessageBox to make sure the problem is not in the textbox but in the value returned by the sql query.

### Table description

[image]

### **Sql query result**

[image]

### Form result

[image]

**iteminformation.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Posfaction
{
    public partial class frmItemInformation : Form
    {
        string fileExtension = ".jpg";
        string ITEM_ID, WarehouseID;
        public frmItemInformation(String VAR_ITEM_ID, String VAR_WarehouseID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ITEM_ID = VAR_ITEM_ID.ToString();
            WarehouseID = VAR_WarehouseID.ToString();
            txtItemID.Text = VAR_ITEM_ID.ToString();
        }
    private void ItemDescription() {
        try
        {
            clsUtility.ExecuteSQLQuery("SELECT *  FROM  ItemInformation  WHERE ITEM_ID ='" + ITEM_ID + "'  ");
            if (clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtItemName.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["ItemName"].ToString();
                txtUnit.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["UnitOfMeasure"].ToString();
                txtBatch.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Batch"].ToString();
                cmbGroup.SelectedValue = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["GROUP_ID"].ToString();
                cmbDefaultWarehouse.SelectedValue = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["WarehouseID"].ToString();
                txtBarcode.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Barcode"].ToString();
                //txtPurchaseCost.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Cost"].ToString();
                txtPurchaseCost.Text = Convert.ToString(clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Cost"]);
                txtSalesPrice.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
                txtReorderPoint.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["ReorderPoint"].ToString();

                if (clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["VAT_Applicable"].ToString() == "Y") { cbVATapplicable.Checked = true; }
                else { cbVATapplicable.Checked = false; }

                if (clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Barcode_Applicable"].ToString() == "Y") { chkApplicableBarcode.Checked = true; }
                else { chkApplicableBarcode.Checked = false; }

                try
                {
                    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\Upload\ItemImage\" + clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["PhotoFileName"].ToString();
                    pictureBox1.InitialImage.Dispose();
                    fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["PhotoFileName"].ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception) { pictureBox1.Image = Posfaction.Properties.Resources.No_image_found; }
            }

            clsUtility.ExecuteSQLQuery("SELECT *  FROM  Stock  WHERE ITEM_ID ='" + ITEM_ID + "' AND WarehouseID ='" + WarehouseID + "'  ");
            if (clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                cmbWarehouse.SelectedValue = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["WarehouseID"].ToString();
                cmbShelf.SelectedValue = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["SHELF_ID"].ToString();
                txtOpeningStock.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString();
                try { dtpExpDate.Text = clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["ExpiryDate"].ToString(); }
                catch (Exception) { }

                if (clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Expiry"].ToString() == "Y") { chkExp.Checked = true; }
                else { chkExp.Checked = false; }
            }

            btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
            btnDelete.Enabled = true;
            btnAlter.Enabled = true;

        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    private void frmItemInformation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        btnReset.PerformClick();
        LoadLanguegePack();
        if (ITEM_ID == "0") { }
        else { ItemDescription(); }

    }
}
```

**clsUtility.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
using CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;
//using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Posfaction
{
    class clsUtility
    {
        public static string CnString = Properties.Settings.Default.App_Conn_string;
        public static DataTable sqlDT = new DataTable();
        public static DataTable sqlDT2 = new DataTable();
        public static string UserID;
        public static string UserName;
        public static string UsersPrivilege;

        // Initializing Database Connection
        public static bool DBConnectionInitializing()
        {
            bool functionReturnValue = false;
            try
            {
                SQLiteConnection sqlCon = new SQLiteConnection();
                sqlCon.ConnectionString = CnString;
                sqlCon.Open();
                functionReturnValue = true;
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                functionReturnValue = false;
                Properties.Settings.Default.App_Default_Conn = false;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message, "Error establishing the database connection..", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            return functionReturnValue;
        }
    

    public static DataTable ExecuteSQLQuery(string SQLQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqlCon = new SQLiteConnection(CnString);
            SQLiteDataAdapter sqlDA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SQLQuery, sqlCon);
            SQLiteCommandBuilder sqlCB = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(sqlDA);
            sqlDT.Reset();
            sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.App_Default_Conn = false;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return sqlDT;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you try `((double)clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Cost"]).ToString()` ?

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: ((double)clsUtility.sqlDT.Rows[0]["Cost"]).ToString() ;
I just tried it as you asked, nothing change. same issue .

Comment: How is the value stored in the database (string or number)?  Seeing a comma in the GUI doesn't mean the value is stored as a string in the database.  You are not using parameters in the query so the type of data may not get transferred correctly between the database and the c# application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value like `145,55` which is stored in the column `Cost` is actually a string and not `REAL`, because it contains `,` as the decimal separator.

Do an update in the table to replace all occurrences of `,` to `.` in the column `Cost` and finally cast it to a `REAL` number implicitly by adding `0.0`:

```
UPDATE ItemInformation
SET Cost = REPLACE(Cost, ',', '.') + 0.0
WHERE INSTR(Cost, ',')
```